# Single speed conversion kit

Tags: single-speed, campagnolo

I have an old Battaglin road bike from 1997 that I want to convert to a single speed. My issue is; what conversion kit to buy? The rear hub spline (not sure this is the correct term) has a 4x4 millimeter. I bought a kit on ebay, turns out it doesn't fit and I am guessing it's because the campagnolo free hub uses different dimensions.

here is the item I bought on ebay http://www.ebay.com/itm/Single-Speed-Conversion-and-Cogs-16T-and-18T-8-9-and-10-Speed-Freehub-Body-SS-/251897565819?nma=true&si=3cfysRTM4ElBxkenIFNdiTV97UE%253D&orig_cvip=true&rt=nc&_trksid=p2047675.l2557

Comment: Which kit did you buy?  Specifically, what parts came with it?

Comment: spacers as well as a single cog

Comment: okay, that makes sense.  I don't have personal experience with Campy but the freehub bodies do have different splines. [This](http://www.wiggle.com/gusset-1-er-campag-single-speed-conversion-kit/) looks like it would work for you. Alternatively, you could keep the existing cassette on the frame and just shorten the chain.  Definitely not as clean and you may not get the gear ratio you want...but it's an option.

Comment: keeping the cassette is not an option, not anymore :) butt he gusset you link to looks like a match, thanks

Comment: Campagnolo changed their splines between 8 and 9 speed cassettes, so check which one you have. The Gusset kit is compatible with 9-11-speed one, because 8-speed hasn't been available since early 2000s.

Comment: the bike is from 1997, but Ill make sure to check